# Facebook PHP SDK v5 g2.4 Post to Fan Page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook PHP SDK v5 graph 2.4.

With the code below I can successfully post to my own page, but how can I set it to post to my fan page?

```
try {
    $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $params, $access_token);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

I tried substituting my fan page id into it:

```
$response = $fb->post('/229107363768163/feed', $params, $access_token);
```

but I get the following error:

```
Graph returned an error: Unsupported post request.
```

EDIT: It seems I need a page access token?? Can someone please show me how?

Please help!

Comment: Does Facebook need to approve my app before I can post to a fan page wall?!

Answer (score 1):

1.If you want to Post to a Fan's page then your App should be approved by Facebook's Team.

2. The keyword "/me" doesn't represent just you. It represents every active or logged in user. If the user approves your app then you can post to their wall.

Comment: Thank you for that insight. Can you help explain the error I am receiving?

Comment: Try using this code `$fb->post('/me/feed', $data);`  where $data is the message that you want to post to a user's wall.